# Java: importing csv containing empty fields gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, csv, import, field, filechooser

I've been trying to import a csv file (containing empty fields) by selecting the file with a filechooser into my database. Using the filechooser is important as it is a program to be used by a school and they want to be able to import their new student records every year by importing the excel/csv file they have. Whenever I run the code given below I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at gui.FXMLStudentController$1.run(FXMLStudentController.java:86)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Question is obvious I think. How do I make it work without the error?

Importer class:

```
public class ImportStudents
{
private File file;
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

public ImportStudents(File file) throws IOException 
{
    this.file = file;
}

public List importStudents() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
   try(CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), ';'))
   {
   String[] nextLine;
   boolean notFirst = false;
   while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        if (notFirst) {

             students.add(new Student(nextLine[3], nextLine[1], nextLine[0],nextLine[2]));
        }
        notFirst = true;
    }

   }catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
    return students;
}
}
```

Code in GUI for when import button is pressed:

```
   @FXML
private void importeer(ActionEvent event)
{

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    ImportStudents = importStudents; //importStudents created earlier in the class
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open File");
    try
    {
        importStudents = new ImportStudents(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage));
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    repository.importStudents(importStudents.importeerLeerlingen());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Code in the repository:

```
  public void importStudents(List<Student> students)
{
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (Student : students) 
        {
           em.persist(student);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally
    {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Example from csv file I try to import this way:
As you can see the email is empty most of times (it's for a kindergarten school) but for some it is given.

```
 SurName;Name;E-mail;Class
 Agacseven;Tuana;;3KA
 Ahmedov;Arman;;2KC
 Akcan;Efe;;3KA
 Akcan;Hanzade;;2KC
 Akhtar;Hussain;;1KA
```

Student constructor looks like this

```
public Student(String class, String name, String surNaam, String email) 
{

    this.class = class;
    this.name = name;
    this.surNaam = surNaam;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: Stack trace? Exception? Line thrown at?

Answer (score 0):

How does the Student constructor look? I have hard time finding in the javadocs what valued readNext() puts in the string reference if there is nothing between delimiters. It could be either an empty string or a null (which it seems to be). In that case it might be that what you do in the Student constructor with that value is not legal with null value.

**EDIT**

if that is the case you could either handle the passing of a null value within the constructor or maybe write a static method that would be something like:

```
public static String Convert(String str) {
    return str == null ? "" : str;
}
```

and when instantiating a student do:

```
new Student(Convert(nextLine[3]), ... );
```

Comment: Added the student constructor code to the question. Also tried the convert method but still the same error